# How to debug a CentOS weird networking issue

Tags: centos, networking, debugging

I have a CentOS 7 machine that is continuously copying data to AWS/S3.
However, it has a problem, which I'd be grateful for suggestions on how to debug.

The copy to S3 would go on for hours/days, and then, the network would stop functioning (I have a `cron` job that records a ping to the network every minute, as well as the S3 command `aws s3 cp`, so I know the exact minute it happened).

At that stage, the `NetworkManager` daemon looks fine, the `syslog` and `journalctl -xe` do not show anything out of the ordinary, but the only way to make the network function again is a reboot.

No user on that machine has any scheduled (crontab) jobs for the time the network stopped functioning normally, the machine has a static IP, and up to the moment of the problem, the machine and the network function without issues.

Any ideas on how to debug this issue?

### Edit 1:

Per Artem Tashkinov's suggestion, I added to crontab a call, each minute, to a script that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
ping -c1 1.1.1.1 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
        echo Successful
else
        echo Fail
        systemctl stop NetworkManager
        rmmod r8169
        modprobe r8169
        systemctl start NetworkManager
fi
```

And I'll see if it's able to revive the network when it dies.

### Edit 2:

Even with the script, the network was not revived when it failed.

I enhanced the script though, as I added an external NIC, to see if it'll solve the issue.

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
#
#kernel_module="r8169"  # on-board NIC
#kernel_module="e1000e" # add-on NIC

nic=$( ifconfig | grep -B1 10.60.100 | head -1 | awk -F: '{ print $1 }' )
kernel_module=$( ethtool -i $nic | grep driver | awk '{ print $NF }' )

ping -c1 1.1.1.1 >/dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
#if [ $? -ne 0 ];
then
        echo Successful
else
        echo Fail
        systemctl stop NetworkManager
        rmmod $kernel_module
        modprobe $kernel_module
        systemctl start NetworkManager
fi
```

Comment: You might want to check `dmesg` as well

Comment: Thanks, @annahri, but I mentioned `the syslog [...] do[es] not show anything out of the ordinary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the only way to make the network function again is a reboot

I've had servers like this in the past.

What I did was adding a task into the crontab pinging a known IP address. If it's inaccessible, the network was shut down, the kernel module responsible for the NIC was removed (`rmmod module_name`) and inserted again (`modprobe module_name`) and lastly the network was started again. Please try it.

If it works for you you definitely should [report a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=Red%20Hat%20Enterprise%20Linux%207).

Comment: Thanks @Artem, I'll try it.